# In React with Redux, newTodo without value

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am looking at this redux [example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todomvc/src/components/Header.js), and find one strange code:

```
<TodoTextInput newTodo
               onSave={this.handleSave}
               placeholder="What needs to be done?" />
```

why the newTodo does not have any value? then what value is passed to the component?

thanks

Comment: That's the same as `newTodo={true}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newTodo` [is a boolean](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todomvc/src/components/TodoTextInput.js#L10)

When no value is set it's the same as doing `newTodo={true}` since obviously if it wasn't there it would be `false`.